# Angular 15 ng new app error : The Schematic workflow failed

Tags: angular

I installed Angular v15:

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1500.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.0.4 (cli-only)


C:\Users\hp\Desktop\M2 SIGGT\Angular>ng new app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE app/angular.json (2685 bytes)
CREATE app/tsconfig.json (901 bytes)
CREATE app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.html (23115 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1064 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
⠹ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics: aborted

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-31T08_56_25_788Z-debug-0.log✖ Package install failed, see above.The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

I've tried to use `npm update` and also the check this command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but nothing changed. I appreciate your help - thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the error log. That might show some more information.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --legacy-peer-deps 
npm cache verify 
npm cache clean --force 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

If it doesn't work. Uninstall the latest nodejs version from your computer; try version 16. I hope sou you problem will solve quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Just shift to lower node version. In my case, I shifted from v18 to v16 and it solved the issue.